Signing a system.img
I am having a bit of a problem, and I believe the situation is pretty unique.
I need to flash a system image to my device, however:
• The device's BROM mode has somehow been disabled by a recent firmware update. When trying to flash, myflashtool would continue to try to connect to the device to no avail.
•The device is in fastboot, but the bootloader is locked and cannot be unlocked.
In order to flash the device with a locked bootloader that is in fastboot, the images have to be signed.
I have done some research, but the subject seems pretty obscure. Is the signature that is found in framework-res.apk the signature that defines a 'signed' system.img?
Would appreciate any input.
Thank you.
